# Can I add custom attributes while adding inline scripts?

Tags: wp-admin, javascript, underscore

I need to inject some underscore templates into admin screen without modifying the core. The templates look like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-123">
    <div class="section intro">
        {{{ data.section.intro }}}
    </div>

    <div class="section content">
        {{{ data.section.content }}}
    </div>
    ...
</script>
```

All templates depend on certain script handle, so I thought about using [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) but it doesn't allow me to specify `type` and `id` attribute.

So, is there a hacky solution to add that attributes while adding inline scripts? Or There's a better way?

I really appreciate you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one demo suggestion:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
   wp_enqueue_script(    'my-script', '/my-script.js', ['underscore', 'backbone'], '1.0' );
   wp_add_inline_script( 'my-script', 'alert("hello world");' );

   // Add our template
   if( function_exists( 'wpse_add_inline_tmpl' ) )
       wpse_add_inline_tmpl( 
           $handle = 'my-script', 
           $id     = 'my-tmpl', 
           $tmpl   = '<div class="section intro">{{{ data.section.intro }}}</div>' 
       );

} );
```

where we define our custom `wpse_add_inline_tmpl()` function as:

```
function wpse_add_inline_tmpl( $handle, $id, $tmpl )
{
    // Collect input data
    static $data = [];
    $data[$handle][$id] = $tmpl;

    // Append template for relevant script handle
    add_filter( 
        'script_loader_tag', 
        function( $tag, $hndl, $src ) use ( &$data, $handle, $id )
        {   
            // Nothing to do if no match
            if( ! isset( $data[$hndl][$id] ) )
                return $tag;

            // Script tag replacement aka wp_add_inline_script()
            if ( false !== stripos( $data[$hndl][$id], '</script>' ) )
                $data[$hndl][$id] = trim( preg_replace( 
                    '#<script[^>]*>(.*)</script>#is', 
                    '$1', 
                     $data[$hndl][$id] 
                ) );

            // Append template
            $tag .= sprintf(
                "<script type='text/template' id='%s'>\n%s\n</script>" . PHP_EOL,
                esc_attr( $id ),
                $data[$hndl][$id]
            );

            return $tag;
        }, 
   10, 3 );
}
```

Here we use the `script_loader_tag` filter to inject the template code and use both the *handle* and *id* to reference it.  We also use the *script* tag [replacement](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f645178391426ce859aad0bebf461516e1165123/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L116) from the core `wp_add_inline_script()` function.

Hope you can test this further and modify to your needs. Writing this as a class might be a better approach ;-)

Comment: Thank you! You have saved me a lot of time. It works great!

Comment: ok great, you're welcome @Dan9